# Hide certain elements on one page but have them on every other page

Tags: html, css, navigation, hide, horizontal-scrolling

I've made a horizontal scrolling website and for the navigation I have used linked images. I want the navigation to be fixed on every page except the homepage. Meaning I don't want the navigation to appear on the homepage, What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You cam add css to the homepage anywhere inside of `<style>` tags,

To make it not fixed:

```
<style>
#nav {
      position: relative;
      }
</style>
```

To hide it completely:

```
<style>
#nav {
      display: none;
      }
</style>
```

Just a quick fix. Only add it to the homepage, anywhere is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but you will have to put the navigation bar on every page. Try copying and pasting the code. Or you can put the id only on some pages.  If this is too basic bear with me as my knowledge of CSS and HTML is very basic and I've just started using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a CMS setup. which means you can not easily change styles or remove the nav from the home page. Add an id to the body tag via the CMS theme. IE

```
<style>
#nav {
/* this is the normal for every page but home page */
}
#home #nav {
{ /* this is for home page */
      display: none;
}
</style>
<body id="home"> for home page.
<body id="12-29-2013-something"> for 12/29 post.
```

Likely a theme would already have an id for the body tag for this purpose.

If it is not a CMS then remove the nav from the html code.